# using $(this) inside jQuery callback to update current row

Tags: jquery, callback, this

I'm trying to update content in a selected html row with server data.
I can update the selected html row with static data, or all html rows with server data.
I cannot update the selected html row with server data.

```
$('td.table_with_server_update a').click(function(){    
  var var1=$(this).data('variable1');
```

This updates the selected html row with static content, this is what I want to do, but with server data.

```
   $(this).parent().prev().html('static content');

   $.post("server_side_process.php",{varone: var1}, function(data){
```

Selecting all elements in html table and updating with server data, this works, next I want to update only the "clicked" row with server data

```
   $('td.table_with_server_update').prev().html(data); //updates all html rows
```

This is what I think I want but don't know how to express this. 
I think my problem is $(this) inside the callback function

```
   $(this).parent().prev().html(data); // no error in firebug, but doesn't rewrite html

   });         
  });                                             
});
```

...

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>rewrite this data  </td><td class="table_with_server_update"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-variable1='1'>Update this row</a> </td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>rewrite this data</td><td class="table_with_server_update"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-variable1='2'> Update this row</a></td>  
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside `$.post()` callback is referring to jQuery XHR object and not to the anchor element. You need to save the `this` in the context of anchor element into the variable and access it inside `$.post()` callback.

Try this:

```
$('td.table_with_server_update a').click(function() {
    // save "this" into $this variable directly as jQuery object 
    var $this = $(this);  
    var var1 = $this.data('variable1');

    $this.parent().prev().html('static content');

    $.post("server_side_process.php",{varone: var1}, function(data) {
      $('td.table_with_server_update').prev().html(data); //updates all rows
      // use saved "$this" = anchor instead of "this" = jQuery XHR object
      $this.parent().prev().html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Others' solutions will work just fine, but an alternative is to use the long format of [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post), [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax), and set the `context` option:

```
$('td.table_with_server_update a').click(function(){    
    var var1 = $(this).data('variable1'); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "server_side_process.php",
        data: { varone: var1 },
        context: this, /* Set the context of ajax-related callbacks */
        success: function (data) {
            /* "this" is now correct */
            $(this).parent().prev().html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/vUaUV/